# Calculate percentage of duplicate values within multiple ranges

Tags: excel, excel-formula, duplicates

Example spreadsheet below shows two columns. 
Column A contains shows two different groupings indicated by two grey rows outlines.
Column B contains "assignment modules" for each group.

In Column C I want to indicate the % of duplicate "assignment modules" within each group (note several vertically merged cells).

The number of "assignment modules" differs per grouping. Therefore I cannot use one static range.

Can anyone suggest how I was calculate the number of duplicate "assignment modules" per each group?

Thank you!

E.G

Cell C3 (Merged C3-8) = 83%

Cell C10 (Merged C10-13) = 100%

[image]

Comment: If the group had: Example 1, Example 2, Example 2, Example 1, Example 2. Should the % be 40% based on Example 1 (being first) or 60% based on Example 2 being the most?

Comment: @Michael I would think 100% since all modules are duplicates.

Comment: Thanks. Also, I'm assuming you want a single formula that you can use for each group regardless of the number of rows in the group. This is a little messy when you don't have a dedicated column that repeats the Group number in every single row. In my solution, I'll need to search for the next blank row in column B. Can I assume you'll never have more than 100 rows in any group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an array formula goes that into C3. It searches the next 100 rows of column A to find where the next group starts; this is used to determine the range for the current group. The last group needs a dummy value in the next row of column A to identify the range for the last group.

It's not possible to save array formulas to merged cells, so you'll need to unmerge all cells in column C first. Then enter this formula in C3 and save it by pressing `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER` instead of just `ENTER`:

```
=1-SUM((COUNTIF(OFFSET(B3,0,0,MATCH("*",A3:A101,0)-1),OFFSET(B3,0,0,MATCH("*",A3:A101,0)-1))=1)*1)/(SUM((OFFSET(B3,0,0,MATCH("*",A3:A101,0)-1)<>0)*1))
```

You can then just copy the entire cell and paste it next to the first row of each group. You can then remerge cells in column C if you want.

[image: Formula]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm afraid my merged cells make this very difficult. 
E.g - In my above example 

Cell B10 is merged with B11 - therefore B11 is seen as an empty cell 
Cell B12 is merged with B13 - therefore B13 is seen as an empty cell also. 

Because of this your formula picks up the empty merged cells in Column B therefore returning a value of 0% for Group 3

Comment: Yeah merged cells are the worst. Right now, it is extremely difficult to come up with just 1 formula that can be copied and pasted for each group. Do you need a single formula you can copy and paste, or are you happy to update the range manually for each group? I've updated the formula that handles merged cells in column B and also that you can copy and paste for each group, but it requires a dummy value in column A at the end to identify the end of the last group.

Comment: this is excellent. Exactly what I was looking for. I unmerged the cells - pulled the formula through all cells and it gave me the correct result every time. All that I needed to do was remerge the cells keeping the top value. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

You can use this in Group 1 C column for % Duplicate:

```
=COUNTIF(B3:B8,B3:B8)/ROWS(B3:B8)
```

And this for Group 2:

```
=COUNTIF(B10:B11,B10:B11)/ROWS(B10:B11)
```

Alternatively, you could define each group range as a defined name:

```
=COUNTIF(Group1,Group1)/ROWS(Group1)


=COUNTIF(Group2,Group2)/ROWS(Group2)
```

[image]

EDIT:

Okay, I believe this will always return the percentage of the group that has a duplicate, regardless of order.

```
=1-SUMPRODUCT(ROUNDDOWN(1/COUNTIF(B3:B8,B3:B8),0))/ROWS(B3:B8)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm afraid that this doesn't quite return all the results as I would expect. And I believe it's due to my merged cells...

E.g - In my above example
Cell B10 is merged with B11 - therefore B11 is seen as an empty cell 
Cell B12 is merged with B13 - therefore B13 is seen as an empty cell also.

Because of this using the formula - this returns a value 50%

Is there anyway this formula can not take into consideration any blank cells? Any ideas?

Comment: I worked out that if I change the formula to:  
=COUNTIF(B3:B8,B3:B8)/COUNTA(B3:B8) - it will count only the cells which contain information.
Unfortunately now I think the first part of the formula isn't returning the results I need.
What I see happening is that =COUNTIF(B3:B8,B3:B8) is checking how many times the cell in B3 is duplicated. Not "How many cells (total) are duplicated."

Comment: Okay, I came up with a better solution, I think.

Comment: Unfortunately this was throwing up a DIV/0 reference. Nevertheless my question has been answered above. Thanks again for your help

Comment: That's odd, it works on my end. Glad you've got a solution though!